# Using XOR(^) as MATH operator

Tags: c#, python-3.x, xor

I was migrating some old code from my my company DLL, that was writed in C# to Python, and as i advanced, i encountered some parts of logic that i didn't understand how it works because of the XOR(^) use

These lines are the rewrited code, but with the same logic, and working the same as it was in C# like that:

```
list_content = [1, 2,210, 224, 97]
item_verif = 3
for j in range(len(list_content)):
    item_verif ^= list_content[j]
return item_verif
```

And the item_verif would turn to be like: 3, 2, 0, 210, 50 and 83
I don't undrstand why of those values, because what happen in the code is:

Assuming that item_verif value it's 210, and the next value of list_content would be 224, so it would be something like:

item_verif = 210 ^ 224

And that would result: 50

What it's happening to get that value

I searched through many places and didn't found any solution, so here it's my last resort

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the *question* here? it looks like it is computing a basic hash/checksum, right? what did you expect to see and how is that different to what you are seeing?

Comment: A triival port of Python to C# results in code that works for me: https://dotnetfiddle.net/6IqU7A

Comment: I'm really lost as to what the question here is. I've tested the Python code above to what I assume the C# code is and both yield item_verif values of 3, 2, 0, 210, 50, and 83 as the loop progresses.

Comment: [Python code above with print](https://onecompiler.com/python/3yjhzvygw)

Comment: ported C# version works fine for me [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEUCuA7AHwDcBDKAAgBsBLAZwwH1I8MYXyBecvGAdwG0AuuQDe5AIxpyAJinTxABjnT05AJwB2cgF8A3AFgAUKQrVWAWwZEYUagDNO5AMwHDd6DBJgAFuQAUJuSklDgw5NR4VHSMzKwsAJRGIkbkqeQAAuIAdJlqfmYwlta2dvGuaeEWVjb25AB6XMGhrtpGmTnieQVFNaW6QA===); <strike>what's the Python output?</strike> edit: which matches @ProgrammingLlama's Python output... so... again what is the question?

Comment: It's not a mathematical operator. It's a bitwise operator.

Comment: Sorry, i will Edit the question to be more clearer

Comment: @Nifuji17 "What it's happening to get that value" - I *think* that's what I answered, then; xor is a bitwise operator that takes the bits of two values and smashes them together such that (for each bit pair in turn) if both values are `0` or both values are `1`, the result is `1` - otherwise (i.e. one `0` and one `1`) the result is `1` - i.e. [this truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or#Truth_table)

Comment: Yes @MarcGravell, when i edited the question i haven't seen your answer, i only saw it, when i already edited it.
I'm yet trying to fully understand all that you explained, but i can see that what you answered is correct
Thanks man!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going out on a limb here and assuming that the real question here is "what is this doing, and why?" (I'm making this assumption since the Python seems to give the same output as the most obvious/literal C# translations, so I'm guessing this isn't a code/technical question - the code already seems to have been translated correctly)

All this is doing is using xor to compute a crude hash, xoring the bits of all of the operands - so we can use that number to check ... well, not *equality*, but definitely *non-equality*: if two such hashes are *different*, then the inputs are *definitely* different; if two such hashes are *the same*, we can't say with any *real* confidence that the inputs are the same, but they *could be*. Hash collisions are absurdly easy to force from this implementation, so: don't use it for anything security related. Usually, such hashes are used only to short-circuit the "false" part of a sequence equality test (on the basis that *generally* we'll be comparing non-equal sequences which will *usually* have different hashes, so *usually* this will save time), i.e.

- given two sequences with pre-computed hashes:

  - are the hashes different? return false <==== this is what it allows us to do
  - are the lengths different? return false
  - for each item in turn from both sequences

    - are the corresponding value from the two sequences different? return false
  - return true

Note that this only helps if you already have the hashes for each sequence. You don't want to compute the hash each time if you don't already know it. Short-circuiting in equality tests can *also* actually be *undesirable* in some niche scenarios, where it can be used in timing-based attacks - security code should usually take a constant time to say "no" vs "yes".

But: we can see what is happening in the modified C# version:

```cs
using System;
var list_content = new[] { 1, 2, 210, 224, 97 };
var item_verif = 3;
Console.WriteLine($"  {Convert.ToString(item_verif, 2).PadLeft(8, '0')} ({item_verif})");
foreach (var value in list_content)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"^ {Convert.ToString(value, 2).PadLeft(8, '0')} ({value})");
    item_verif ^= value;
    Console.WriteLine($"= {Convert.ToString(item_verif, 2).PadLeft(8, '0')} ({item_verif})");
}
```

which outputs:

```
  00000011 (3)
^ 00000001 (1)
= 00000010 (2)
^ 00000010 (2)
= 00000000 (0)
^ 11010010 (210)
= 11010010 (210)
^ 11100000 (224)
= 00110010 (50)
^ 01100001 (97)
= 01010011 (83)
```

Comment: That wasn't really "used" for cybersecurity, it was used to create parity bytes of an message body, that would be send some screen with Socket connection, but your explanation it's really good and helped me to clear my doubt Thanks again!

Comment: @Nifuji17 just a thought: this could probably be vectorized and/or parallelized for a nice perf bump, if it is just for parity

Comment: In Python i'm already using geneartors to help with a little with performance.
As I'm not the creator of the original code, I don't know why he used that way of creating a parity byte, now I'm only following the way he did, because if it isn't in that way, the message don't appear on the screen